# How to change height of ui-grid row?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I am using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info). I have a lot of rows and that is why I use scrolling. Everything works perfectly ok until I try to change the height of the rows. Then the scrolling becomes a mess. I have added an example here http://plnkr.co/edit/S6ylwOVgcQp7CSsZZxpR?p=preview
This is one of the tutorials from the ui-grid website - the only thing I have changed is the CSS. I have added these rules.

```
.ui-grid-cell-contents {
  padding: 1px 1px;
}

.ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-header-cell,
.ui-grid-render-container-left .ui-grid-header-cell,
.grid .ui-grid-row,
.grid .ui-grid-cell,
.grid .ui-grid-cell .ui-grid-vertical-bar {
  height: 22px !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-header-cell,
.ui-grid-render-container-left .ui-grid-header-cell,
ui-grid-header-cell {
  height: 55px !important;
}
.ui-grid-filter-container {
  padding: 1px 3px;
}
```

Scrolling works perfectly ok if the above CSS rules are removed.
So I either need to add more CSS rules or I need to use some API of the grid in order to set row height properly.
Any help will be much appreciated.

How do I change row height and keep scrolling smooth?

**UPDATE**:
Here is a comparison between a default grid and one with modified CSS:
http://plnkr.co/edit/x1nQGvpkY4bRMs9D09Ws?p=preview
try to scroll the rows up and down for each grid. The difference should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Take out the:

```
height: 22px !important;
```

from the css and add:

```
rowHeight:22
```

to the gridOptions.

I have the feeling that this is much smoother.

[Forked Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KyeJqGYL3kRFNgXc9rEZ?p=preview)

Comment: I don't like this solution. When the grid height matches that of the screen, changing the CSS here messes with the scolling behavior. It can't calculate the row height properly, because, I suspect, it uses the rowHeight value in code rather than measuring the offsetHeight()

Answer (score 22):

scope.gridOptions = {
          rowHeight: 33
}
The best way of changing the row height is from the grid options.

Comment: Why is this the best way? i find css much easier.

Comment: Because ui-grid needs row height in javascript for calculation. By changing it with CSS you mess up row display

Answer (score 8):

Try add this to your css:

```
.ui-grid-viewport .ui-grid-cell-contents {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal !important;
}

.ui-grid-row, .ui-grid-cell {
  height: auto !important;
}

.ui-grid-row div[role=row] {
  display: flex ;
  align-content: stretch;
}
```

Comment: is there a performance impact due to any affect on virtualization?

Comment: No, I use it at work and it works fine with no delay or any impact

Comment: I found  "padding-top: 5px;" also useful in addition to the auto height;

Answer (score 0):

Just alter **grid** class accordingly.

```
.grid{
    height: 70vh;
}
```